# What software to use to write a multi-section sefer?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, hebrew, english

What software is available that allows Hebrew and English and multiple sections?   i.e. the main section and then a footnote/pirush (section #2) on that, and then a 3rd section which footnotes items in section #2 providing further עיון.  This is very common in seforim, but I don't know what software is used.

thanks in advance
Nov 2022 Update - Mellel.com has a [great feature](https://youtu.be/FLpyQoxIMlk?t=635) of allowing multiple note "streams" which can keep track of different notes (e.g. notes on the main section vs. notes on the עיון section.
Q- However it's mac only - anyone know of windows s/w  with this feature?

Also with help @magicker72 I found a perfect add in to Adobe Indesign  id-extras.com/products/footwork which is exactly what was looking for (they even show a sefer as an example) - though very expensive add in $385

Comment: Check with Art Scroll as to the software that it uses for the gemarrah.

Comment: @Sabbahillel I had always made up that it was custom, but of course I don’t know. Maybe there are some details in the zlotowitz biography

Comment: A lot of seforim use Davka Writer

Comment: When I did my mock Artscroll some time back I used Apple’s Pages app.

Comment: You should look at Mellel by Uri Redler. It does all that you are seeking and more. See here: https://www.mellel.com

Comment: @DonielF did you already share a link here? I don't recall and assume it must have been very good

Comment: You could ask Raphael Freeman, a Jewish typesetter, see https://www.renanatype.com/

Comment: I repeat, Mellel is exactly what you are looking for. I am also in commercial printing and work in multiple languages including Hebrew. If you want to spend more money, you should consider InDesign Middle Eastern version. You can do anything with it, but it’s probably way more than you need and is a lot more money than Mellel.

Comment: @Yaacov Why don’t you post that as an answer?

Comment: @DonielF I am assuming this is off topic and will get closed, but wanted to help the OP.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at the mellel video - I like the conditional references in mellel.  Does it also have multiple sections on a page (e.g. the way the mishneh berurah and tons of other seforim are printed)?

Comment: ARe you sure about the handling of multiple sections b/c I emailed Mellel as follows "Does mellel also have multiple sections on a page (e.g. the way the mishneh berurah and tons of other seforim are printed)?  So that the text on each page flows to the approratiate section on the next page throughout the book"  and they responded that they do not

Comment: This can be done with InDesign with some [scripting](https://typefiwebcontent.s3.amazonaws.com/Resources/InDesign/201703_InDesignMagazine_Footnotes.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, I contacted the author and he referenced me to https://www.id-extras.com/products/footwork/  which is exactly what  was looking for (they even show a sefer as an example) - though very expensive add in $385

Comment: Feel free to update us also with what you've written!